# png image from nodejs server not usable in ionic angular google maps native marker

Tags: node.js, angular, express, google-maps, ionic-framework

right now I am loading all of my images from the server url. In HTML it looks like

```
<img [src]="http://myserverurl.../image.png" />
```

and this is working fine. I can see the images on the profiles. But I am also using the google maps native ionic plugin and it won't load my images from the same path. At first I thought I made some mistakes but after verifying everything it correct I was trying another png from wikipedia which was loading as well.
Afterwards I took the image, which is not loading from my server and uploaded it to an image upload service. Referencing to this image in my application is working in google maps plugin, referring the same image from my nodejs server is not.

I am using express and a public folder for providing those images.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Path for example: http://192.168.178.35:4000/uploads/images/group/thumb_60f95db8d280a0639f188a6a.png

I can also access the image in the browser, so I have no clue what could be the problem. Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Google Maps Plugin: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Answer (score -1):

That path contains the IP for your local network. I imagine using a public IP should solve your issues if wikipedia images are working fine.

Comment: I have tried referencing to our test server which is referencing to a domain containg a certificate. Same images do not work there as well.